# Resolve relative or absolute path relative to another path

Tags: python, python-3.x, path

Given a path that may be absolute or relative, I'd like to resolve its absolute path relative to another given path (if it's relative), without changing the current directory.

For example, assuming the current working directory is `/cwd`:

```
def resolve_path (relative_to, path_to_resolve):
    ???

resolve_path(".", "a/relative/path")
# --> returns /cwd/a/relative/path

resolve_path("example", "a/relative/path")
# --> returns /cwd/example/a/relative/path

resolve_path("/some/path", "a/relative/path")
# --> returns /some/path/a/relative/path

resolve_path("/some/path", "..")
# --> returns /some

resolve_path("/some/path", "/an/absolute/path")
# --> returns /an/absolute/path

resolve_path("/some/path", "/.")
# --> returns /
```

Is there something in `os.path` (or somewhere else) that does this (Python 3.8 minimum)?

Comment: Have you looked into [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)?

Comment: @JRiggles I don't know much about it but I will read through it now, thank you.

Comment: @JRiggles Which function are you suggesting? I found `relative_to()`, but it does the opposite -- it returns the relative path.

Comment: Oh, as it turns out, `os.path.join` (combined with `os.path.abspath`) already does exactly what I need; I don't know why I thought it didn't. From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html): *"If a segment is an absolute path ... then all previous segments are ignored and joining continues from the absolute path segment."*

Comment: @Barmar I wasn't suggesting any one function in particular - I'm not aware of a single function within `pathlib` that handles this

Comment: @JasonC And the pathlib equivalent is `joinpath()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, `os.path.join` already does exactly what I need, after running its result through `os.path.abspath`.

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) for `os.path.join`:

> If a segment is an absolute path ... then all previous segments are ignored and joining continues from the absolute path segment.

So the function I'm looking for is simply:

```
def resolve_path (relative_to, path_to_resolve):
    return os.path.abspath(os.path.join(relative_to, path_to_resolve))
```

The results of that match the desired results:

```
user@magic:/cwd# python
>>> import os.path
>>> def resolve_path (relative_to, path_to_resolve):
...     return os.path.abspath(os.path.join(relative_to, path_to_resolve))
... 
>>> resolve_path(".", "a/relative/path")
'/cwd/a/relative/path'
>>> resolve_path("example", "a/relative/path")
'/cwd/example/a/relative/path'
>>> resolve_path("/some/path", "a/relative/path")
'/some/path/a/relative/path'
>>> resolve_path("/some/path", "..")
'/some'
>>> resolve_path("/some/path", "/an/absolute/path")
'/an/absolute/path'
>>> resolve_path("/some/path", "/.")
'/'
```